# Failed opening required ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I setup my symfony project (version 1.4) on Centos Linux VPS following all the instructions. When I open this file htp://myserver/backend.php I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect.     File(/var/www/html/myproject/web/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (.) in /var/www/html/myproject/web/backend.php on line 4

Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/myproject/web/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/myproject/web/backend.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/myproject/web/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/myproject/web/backend.php on line 4
```

Safe mode is disabled in php.ini and in httpd.conf

The file backend.php on line 4 has:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
```

This:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php';
```

returns

```
/var/www/html/myproject/web/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
```

What is wrong in there ?
I cannot figure out why is not working.

Comment: Im confused, you're trying to load sfCoreAutoLoad.class.php, and the error is for ProjectConfiguration.class.php?

Comment: Can it be an include_path problem ?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

I added in the httpd.conf these lines:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    php_admin_value open_basedir none
</Directory>
```

I don't know if this issue happens only in centos but the safe_mode disabled is not enough. open_basedir should be set to NONE.